# start + infinitive/gerund

Tags: grammar, infinitives, gerunds

> 1.
>   It is high time he started **to look** into his own flaws before speaking ill of others.
>
> 2.
>   It is high time he started **looking** into his own flaws before speaking ill of others.

I think 1st one is correct because verb "start" followed by an Infinitive.

Which one is correct?

And one more question Is there any specific rule to use gerund and infinitive or  i just have to memorize verbs which followed by infinitive and gerund?.

Answer (score 3):

Both are equally correct.

I'd say that the second one is slightly better, though, because **looking** is meant to contrast with **speaking**. By using the same form in both places—“grammatical parallelism”—you make the intended contrast clearer to the listener.

There is no rule for which verbs are followed by a gerund, which are followed by an infinitive, and which allow both. Even worse, a few verbs change their meaning depending on whether you follow them with a gerund or an infinitive. [This question on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/when-should-a-verb-be-followed-by-a-gerund-instead-of-an-infinitive) has a list.