# He stopped to work or he stopped to works?

Tags: infinitives

Which is correct?

He stopped to work or he stopped to work**s**?

I know he work**s** and I work is correct but I am not sure for case above.

---

<sub><sup>(Clarification of context from OP in a now-deleted "answer", registered under a different UserID to that of the original ELU question)</sup></sub>

> *If someone **has worked** for the previous three years on some project, **but not anymore**.*

Comment: If he was working and now he stopped, it's _he stopped working_. If he was doing something else, and he interrupted that so that he could start working, _he stopped to work_. Only conjugate one verb per clause. _Stopped_ is conjugated for _he_, so you do not conjugate _work_. But _do_ check what you mean to say!

Comment: possible duplicate of [start + infinitive/gerund](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43989/start-infinitive-gerund) But note that ***stop*** and ***start*** work slightly differently here, in that *He started to work* and *He started working* can both mean he wasn't previously working and now he is, but idiomatically we *can't* use *He stopped to work* to mean the same as *He stopped working* (he *was* previously working and now he *isn't*).

Comment: [This ELU question of mine](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64325/) is probably a bit too specialized for the current OP at the moment. But it may interest others who (like me) find it slightly odd that a superficially "mirror image" pair of verbs like ***to stop / to start*** have significantly different syntactic restrictions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yah, I don't think we can cite that Q as a duplicate, precisely because *stop* with the marked infinitive has a distinct meaning. Let's leave it open.

Comment: @StoneyB: I don't often class ELL questions as "Too Basic" - how do I know what is (or *should be*) obvious or easily looked up from any given NNS's perspective? But I might have considered it in this case were it not also a duplicate (from *my* perspective, obviously! :) Not to mention which we're only *guessing* at OP's intended sense unless he provides a clarifying edit. But any exploration of contrived alternatives such as *He stopped **doing** [something else], **by** [at some place], ]*, or ***remained** [in order to work]* would probably only confuse the OP here.

Comment: Underlying this question appears to be the issue of whether the infinitive is inflected to express number. It is not duplicative as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

He stopped to work or stopped works

If the OP has used work in the sense of the job he does to earn money,  both the sentences don't convey this sense.

He stopped works.  Work is an uncountable noun.  The correct sentence should be "He stopped work".

He stopped to work.  It's also incorrect for the intended sense.  If you want to say that he was no longer continuing to work, you can say:

He stopped working.

If you say that he stopped to do something, it means that he stopped what he was doing in order to do something else.  For example, you can say " He stopped to work (operate) the machine. He stopped to help the old man pass the road.

Answer (score -1):

Two meanings:

stopped, to {bare infinitive} = ceased what I|he|she|it|we|they had been doing, in order to do something else.

stopped {verb}-ing = ceased {verb}-ing

**The horse stopped, to drink from the stream.

I stopped, to look at the horse drinking.

The horse stopped drinking, and walked up the hill.**

Answer (score -2):

A basic sentence is made up of a clause and a phrase. Verbs in clauses need to be conjugated, but verbs in phrases take the infinitive form. A clause is made up of a subject, verb and object or just a subject and verb.

The clause in your sentence is *He stopped*. (He = subject; stopped = verb)

Since "to work" is not part of the clause in your sentence, it needs to be written in the infinitive form, "to work".

Concisely, the correct sentence is:

> He stopped to **work**.

Comment: This is a relatively meaningless answer. As oerkelens originally commented, both the infinitive *and* the continuous participle are valid in OP's example, *depending on the intended sense*. But per my own comment, if we changed the main verb from ***stop*** to ***start***, the infinitive and the participle forms ***to work / working*** would both effectively mean the same thing.